# Printing Left and Right Subtree in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

My instructor has a specific output requirement for the way that the Binary Tree should be printed. 
He wants the output to be like so:

root {  left_subtree  }-{  right_subtree  }

i.e:

12 {18} --{24}

18 {6} --{14}

6 {NULL} --{NULL}

etc...

I did not realize this till today, and I was already excited that I got my program to work.

```
template<class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
    elemType info;
    nodeType<elemType> *lLink;
    nodeType<elemType> *rLink;
};

template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::printPreOrder(nodeType<elemType> *root1)
{
    if(root1 != NULL) {
        cout<<root1->info<<" "<<"{"<<root1->lLink<<"}"<<endl;//this is where I get the errors 
        printPreOrder(root1->lLink);
        printPreOrder(root1->rlink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::insert(const elemType&  insertItem){

    nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
    nodeType<elemType> *newNode;  //pointer to create the node

    newNode = new nodeType<elemType>;    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = NULL;
    newNode->rLink = NULL;


    if (root1 == NULL)
        root1 = newNode;
    else {   
        current = root1;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            if (current->info == insertItem)
            {
                cout << "The item to be inserted is already "; 
                cout << "in the tree -- duplicates are not allowed." << endl;
                return;        
            }
            else if (current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }//end while

        if (trailCurrent->info >insertItem)
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;       
        else
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;    
    }
}
```

How would I get my function to print out the left subTree and the right subTree.  Everytime I try something I get a segmentation fault or weird memory address are output.

I am looking for guidance and help, anything from pseudo code to how to do it would be awesome.  I am just confused

EDITED: To include the insert function and what I do when I get the errors

Comment: Your `printPreOrder` looks good. What is your implementation of insert methods? Do you always set lLink, rLink to NULL ?

Comment: lLink and rLink are indeed set to NULL when I insert

Comment: show us complete example when you have segfault and/or, other errors.

Comment: Also, realize that you have to print the `NULL`s as in the example `6 {NULL} --{NULL}`

Comment: Your code as given does not compile, I've made some changes to your braces where the fix likely is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something along these lines:

```
template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::printPreOrder(nodeType<elemType> *root) {
   if( root ) { 
        cout << root->info << " " << endl;

        cout << "{";
        if( root->left ) {
            cout << root->left->info;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NULL";
        }
        cout << "} -- ";

        cout << "{";
        if( root->right ) {
            cout << root->right->info;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NULL";
        }
        cout << "}";

        cout << endl;

        printPreOrder( root->left );

        printPreOrder( root->right );
   }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, left is just lLink and right is just rLink... I think

Comment: This solution does not print {NULL} for empty tree and prints doubled info for each not-root nodes...